# php sql join type

Tags: php, mysql, join

Im trying to optimize my PHP code, the queries particularly.

This code finds out if the player actually has any of the weapon he has equipped ($firearm).

What kind of mysql JOIN do i need to combine these 2 into 1 query:

```
    $firearm = "Sniper Rifle"; // example
    $sql_result2 = mysql_query("SELECT shortname FROM db_firearms WHERE name='firearm'", $db); $rs2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result2);
    $sql_result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items_firearms WHERE player='$id'", $db); $rs3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result3);
    if ($rs3[$rs2[shortname]] < 1) { mysql_query("UPDATE mobsters SET firearm = '' WHERE id ='$id'"); }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [mySQL query needs join?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972988/mysql-query-needs-join)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to combine these queries.

1. Queries return probably different columns amount and different data
2. This will not improve and optimize anything

Comment: And, which field to join on? Not visible at all from the OP.

Comment: @hakre: I bet that OP just doesn't understand what `JOIN` does

Comment: well i need to pull data from one table to be able to get the data from the 2nd. Wondered if I could get to the end result in one query instead of 2

Comment: @user1022585: Sorry, cannot get what your code does for now :-S